# What is causing these display bugs?

Tags: graphics, display

Since I installed 14.04 I have some annoying display bugs. Everything works fine except for some stripes which appear sometimes in the [window switcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFTbk.png) and on the [maximize button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2poK7.png) for example. Any idea what might solve this?

I am using a Dell Inspiron 1545 with an onboard Intel card

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
```

Comment: Could you pleasse add screenshots? Also please provode more details about your hardware such as processor, any graphics card etc.

Comment: I did include two screenshots. http://i.imgur.com/zpi4tiA.png and http://i.imgur.com/JvHCNyn.png